# Order By in subquerys in Sybase SQL

Tags: sybase

I have this table.  TABLE1

```
ID     NAME       QTA

102    Name 1     100

105    Name 2       0

107    Name 3      10

109    Name 4       0

110    Name 5       7
```

I want to Order in this way.    ( BY ID WHERE QTA >0  then BY ID WHERE QTA = 0 )

```
ID     NAME       QTA

102    Name 1     100

107    Name 3      10

110    Name 5       7

105    Name 2       0

109    Name 4       0
```

I try this query

```
SELECT ID, NAME, QTA
FROM TABLE1
WHERE QTA > 0
ORDER BY ID   

UNION 

SELECT ID, NAME, QTA
FROM TABLE1
where QTA = 0 
ORDER BY ID
```

The problem is that ORDER BY is not allowed in subquerys.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that order in the `ORDER BY`, just add a `CASE`:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, QTA
FROM TABLE1
WHERE QTA >= 0
ORDER BY CASE WHEN QTA > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the order by before union.